# add a class to elements with specific classes in vue.js 3

Tags: css, vue.js, styles, vuejs3

I have a list of classes and I want to add one class to any element with these classes. for example:

```
classes = {
  "one",
  "two",
  "three"
}
```

in this example, I want to add  'red' class to any element with one of these classes. in this case, I can do it manually but in my case, the elements and classes are about 20! I want a programmatically way.

how to do it in vue.js 3?

Comment: Can't you use document.getElementsByClassName('one two three') and you can use this.$el for element selector

Comment: what have tried so far?